# YouTube API OAuth redirect URI in Docker Container

Tags: python, docker, flask, youtube-api

I'm trying to build a website with a Flask backend where I can upload videos to youtube. I'm already through the quota and able to upload videos through a script if I run it as a local webserver.

Now the problem is that I'm not sure what I need to use as a redirect URI when I want to deploy it in a Docker Container. I thought I can just set the URI in the Google console to https://vod.mydomain.dev/oauth2callback and adjust the `oauth` and change it in my code but I always get this error:

```
oauthlib.oauth2.rfc6749.errors.MismatchingStateError: (mismatching_state) CSRF Warning! State not equal in request and response.
```

But I don't understand why. So my question is how can you Authorize google via `oauth` on a webpage deployed in a docker container?

```
import os
import google.oauth2.credentials
import google_auth_oauthlib.flow
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload

from flask import Flask, request, redirect, session, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = os.urandom(24)

# Ersetzen Sie YOUR_CLIENT_ID und YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET mit Ihren eigenen Werten
os.environ['GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID'] = 
os.environ['GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET'] = 
os.environ['OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT'] = '1'

CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE = "client_secret.json"
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload']


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Hello World! <a href="/authorize">Authorize</a> '+ url_for('oauth2callback', _external=True, _scheme='https')
    

@app.route('/authorize')
def authorize():
    flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.Flow.from_client_secrets_file(
        CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
    flow.redirect_uri = url_for('oauth2callback', _external=True, _scheme='https')
    authorization_url, state = flow.authorization_url(
        access_type='offline',
        include_granted_scopes='true')

    session['state'] = state
    print(session['state'],flow.redirect_uri)
    return redirect(authorization_url)


@app.route('/oauth2callback')
def oauth2callback():
    state = session['state']

    flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.Flow.from_client_secrets_file(
        CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE, scopes=SCOPES, state=state)
    flow.redirect_uri = url_for('oauth2callback', _external=True)

    authorization_response = request.url
    flow.fetch_token(authorization_response=authorization_response)

    credentials = flow.credentials
    session['credentials'] = {
        'token': credentials.token,
        'refresh_token': credentials.refresh_token,
        'token_uri': credentials.token_uri,
        'client_id': credentials.client_id,
        'client_secret': credentials.client_secret,
        'scopes': credentials.scopes
    }

    return redirect('/upload_video')


@app.route('/upload_video')
def upload_video():
    if 'credentials' not in session:
        return redirect('authorize')

    credentials = google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials(**session['credentials'])

    try:
        youtube = build('youtube', 'v3', credentials=credentials)

        body = {
            "snippet": {
                "categoryId": "22",
                "description": "Beschreibung des Videos",
                "title": "Funktioniert der Automatische Upload?"
            },
            "status": {
                "privacyStatus": "private"
            }
        }

        video_file = "/clips/Test.mp4"
        media = MediaFileUpload(video_file, mimetype='video/mp4', chunksize=-1, resumable=True)

        request = youtube.videos().insert(
            part=",".join(body.keys()),
            body=body,
            media_body=media
        )

        response = request.execute()
        return f'Video wurde erfolgreich hochgeladen: {response}'

    except HttpError as error:
        return f'Ein Fehler ist aufgetreten: {error}'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=443)
```

I tried to run the script directly and use a local webserver and everything worked fine.

Then I tried to create a docker container and I'm still able to get to the login screen but the moment it tries to redirect me back to my own domain I get an error and it crashes.

Comment: you need a web server on a registered domain hosted in your docker container

Comment: i already had this. the problem was that i forgot the _scheme='https' flag in the /oauth2callback  route and because of this i had a uri missmatch (http != https)